# xpath choose all text() but not from specific tag / class attribute

Tags: xpath

I want to ask a question:

The structure is like:

```
<div class='item'>
    <div class='all'>
       BY
       <p>ABC</p>
       <p>DEF</p>
       <p>
         <span class="date">19991111</span>
       </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to ask how to choose all the `text()`(BY ABC DEF) but not contains  `<span class="date">DDD</span>`(19991111)

I found `not()`method `span[not(@class, 'date')`
but don't know how to combine with  `//div[@class=item]/div[@class='all']//text()`

Please teach me Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them like this :

```
//div[@class=item]/div[@class='all']//text()[not(parent::span[@class='date'])]
```

Above XPath select all text nodes within the `div[@class='all']` which parent is not matched by `span[@class='date']`.

You may want to also filter out empty text nodes using `normalize-space()` :

```
//div[@class=item]/div[@class='all']//text()[not(parent::span[@class='date']) and normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `descendant-or-self` axis with a `*` selector with predicate `not(self::span and @class='date')`.

For example

```
//div[@class='item']/div[@class='all']/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::span and @class='date')]/text()
```

Demo here ~ http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/405026153e7beb1847d023f2553674b7